# IE 9 update has killed these drop menus

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Every other browser displays these rollouts under About and Resources fine but IE 9 won't show them.

http://www.preemiestoday.com/pages/about_contact.php

My CSS looks like this:

```
#aboutRollout {
    position:absolute;
    left:inherit;
    top:193px;
    width:200px;
    height:170px; // added today trying to fix this
    z-index:5;
    background-color:#CAD5EC;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding-top:5px;
    z-index:100;
}
#aboutRollout LI {
    border:none;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:11px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    clear:both;
}

#aboutRollout LI A {
    background-color:#CAD5EC;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#aboutRollout LI A:HOVER {
    background-color:#CAD5EC;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<li  id='link1'><a href='/pages/about.php'  onmouseover='showabout()'  onmouseout='hideabout()'>About Us<div id="aboutRollout" style="display:none" onmouseover="showabout()"  onmouseout="hideabout()"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="pages/about.php">Mission</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_board.php">Board Members and Staff</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_donate.php">Donate</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_partners.php">Partners</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_contact.php">Contact</a></li> 
</ul></div></a></li>
```

And the JS looks like this:

```
function showabout() {
document.getElementById('aboutRollout').style.display='block';
}
function hideabout() {
document.getElementById('aboutRollout').style.display='none';
}
```

Can anyone see why IE9 shows an empty box and that only if I define height?

Checked in IE8, IE9, Chrome, FF, and windows Safari.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: probably unrelated, but you seem to have defined `z-index` twice in your `#aboutRollout` CSS.

Comment: Thanks.  Corrected now.  Was clasping at straws and added that without noticing the original declaration.

Comment: @jerry: Grasping at straws? :)

Comment: @jerry - Is there any particular reason why you're using JavaScript to do this? You can use pure CSS to achieve the same effect, probably with less hassle in most situations.

Comment: @Shauna - At least in past IE's behavior around :hover was not helpful

Comment: @jerry - Only IE6 doesn't play well with `:hover`, and even then, IMO, a line or two of non-intrusive JS that you can sandbox with conditional comments is better than inline JS for all browsers, even if they implement `:hover` and dropdown menus perfectly. That said, unless you still have to support IE6 (and if you do and can't do anything about that, I feel sorry for you), it might be worthwhile to consider refactoring your code.

Comment: @Shauna _ I hear you but I don't think it bears on this bizarre visibility issue; do you?

Comment: @Jerry - That's why I didn't put it as an answer, though it might solve your problem. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the block-level element (div) inside the inline element (anchor).

So the DIV was replaced by an LI:

```
<li  id='link1' onmouseover='showabout()'  onmouseout='hideabout()'><a href='/pages/about.php'>About Us</a><li id="aboutRollout" style="display:none" onmouseover="showabout()"  onmouseout="hideabout()"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="/pages/about.php">Mission</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_board.php">Board Members and Staff</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_donate.php">Donate</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_partners.php">Partners</a></li> 
<li><a href="/pages/about_contact.php">Contact</a></li> 
</ul></li>
```

And the outer UL was assigned position:relative and I adjusted the positions of the rollouts.